# pyqt5 QTableWidget won't display id key value from PyEve dataset

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, qtablewidget

i'm trying to build a pyqt5 widget to display a dataset from PyEve, but i'm unable to display the id key value into the table row header. this is the part of the code that generate the QTableWidget

```
http = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people"
con = requests.get(http)

self.tview = QTableWidget()
self.tview.setRowCount(len(con.json()['_items']))
self.tview.setColumnCount(2)

self.tview.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QTableWidgetItem("Firstname"))
self.tview.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QTableWidgetItem("Lastname"))

row = 0
for item in con.json()['_items']:
    self.tview.setVerticalHeaderItem(row, QTableWidgetItem(item["id"]))
    self.tview.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(item['firstname']))
    self.tview.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(item['lastname']))
    row += 1
```

which resulted:
[QTableWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZffNs.png)

this is the dataset from the API call in shell

> ```
>     $ http localhost:5000/people
>
>     {
>     "_items": [
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "34418931281956ee9f0d73f5015a325276dce0a8",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/1",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "George",
>             "fullname": "George Washington",
>             "id": 1,
>             "lastname": "Washington"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "8efc3ef35256de6e9bf530e54188ba5c3526cf0b",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/2",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "John",
>             "fullname": "John Adams",
>             "id": 2,
>             "lastname": "Adams"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "b1e81fb3519dda0d723043203c06c2df235c9450",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/3",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Thomas",
>             "fullname": "Thomas Jefferson",
>             "id": 3,
>             "lastname": "Jefferson"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "5d3bc841cefdb56710445b2cf9d89c3a0c899551",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/4",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "George",
>             "fullname": "George Clinton",
>             "id": 4,
>             "lastname": "Clinton"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "a83d11293f00374f91f66ae9da5373dc6c924bca",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/5",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "James",
>             "fullname": "James Madison",
>             "id": 5,
>             "lastname": "Madison"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "e6abc69c3f2cb05676b0f2e6d76bde51b3ee467c",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/6",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Elbridge",
>             "fullname": "Elbridge Gerry",
>             "id": 6,
>             "lastname": "Gerry"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "5621734381fe51fc4bb6d05bdc94ffe2cfe91c75",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/7",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "James",
>             "fullname": "James Monroe",
>             "id": 7,
>             "lastname": "Monroe"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "a03e9261c3a06526893ba074f62b939d9f7798ed",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/8",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "John",
>             "fullname": "John Adams",
>             "id": 8,
>             "lastname": "Adams"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "1b7c8e7674a75e876547567839f0496f4e2f893e",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/9",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Andrew",
>             "fullname": "Andrew Jackson",
>             "id": 9,
>             "lastname": "Jackson"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "975dd0527d63b8bb10fe63c6d648df8eaafc1a4d",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/10",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Martin",
>             "fullname": "Martin Van Buren",
>             "id": 10,
>             "lastname": "Van Buren"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "d2aed37174724a07dd4f3262b703490319c9aa9a",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/11",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "William",
>             "fullname": "William Harrison",
>             "id": 11,
>             "lastname": "Harrison"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "60938a8ea70dc4be7082dc12510c19bd2d802623",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/12",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "John",
>             "fullname": "John Tyler",
>             "id": 12,
>             "lastname": "Tyler"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "f158fb234f0be3da9701779bcc953311bcaf9e89",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/13",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "James",
>             "fullname": "James Polk",
>             "id": 13,
>             "lastname": "Polk"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "32cd09027db237a97c1d26a365403385e7eb9e40",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/14",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Zachary",
>             "fullname": "Zachary Taylor",
>             "id": 14,
>             "lastname": "Taylor"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "9c211e916acb0327c2cc02f71a894e1f445d21ba",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/15",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Millard",
>             "fullname": "Millard Fillmore",
>             "id": 15,
>             "lastname": "Fillmore"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "f8d4dc8f5d8ffed19cdd5304c66a5f930e085fcb",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/16",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Franklin",
>             "fullname": "Franklin Pierce",
>             "id": 16,
>             "lastname": "Pierce"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "1b64a097904bb043e9d52f85c0620d5743fe41f7",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/17",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "James",
>             "fullname": "James Buchanan",
>             "id": 17,
>             "lastname": "Buchanan"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "dbc84c7bffdcaa6268f64556db373f96a308025c",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/18",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Abraham",
>             "fullname": "Abraham Lincoln",
>             "id": 18,
>             "lastname": "Lincoln"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "c9e29f8cc5b81bc406336780fbdd211490af33c6",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/19",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Andrew",
>             "fullname": "Andrew Johnson",
>             "id": 19,
>             "lastname": "Johnson"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "b3ebe09856c4e5e6e04a5e5fb88c087f5cf93165",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/20",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Ulysses",
>             "fullname": "Ulysses Grant",
>             "id": 20,
>             "lastname": "Grant"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "e874ccb8f1ff91efb4f25d0d86ac0d1c15ba9260",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/21",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Henry",
>             "fullname": "Henry Wilson",
>             "id": 21,
>             "lastname": "Wilson"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "a62dd991fd36fdfc427c6823ecd1baf9b9a2a55f",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/22",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Rutherford",
>             "fullname": "Rutherford Hayes",
>             "id": 22,
>             "lastname": "Hayes"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "21071baad27a9fed4ed01be7b32b7962fabd9414",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/23",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "James",
>             "fullname": "James Garfield",
>             "id": 23,
>             "lastname": "Garfield"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "cdbd9450d58cd7258ce977cbf89a13efc3bd05df",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/24",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Chester",
>             "fullname": "Chester Arthur",
>             "id": 24,
>             "lastname": "Arthur"
>         },
>         {
>             "_created": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "_etag": "f6d202e5f0ef01ccc1bc73a215e93378935bac0b",
>             "_links": {
>                 "self": {
>                     "href": "people/25",
>                     "title": "person"
>                 }
>             },
>             "_updated": "Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:33:50 GMT",
>             "firstname": "Grover",
>             "fullname": "Grover Cleveland",
>             "id": 25,
>             "lastname": "Cleveland"
>         }
>     ],
>     "_links": {
>         "last": {
>             "href": "people?page=3",
>             "title": "last page"
>         },
>         "next": {
>             "href": "people?page=2",
>             "title": "next page"
>         },
>         "parent": {
>             "href": "/",
>             "title": "home"
>         },
>         "self": {
>             "href": "people",
>             "title": "people"
>         }
>     },
>     "_meta": {
>         "max_results": 25,
>         "page": 1,
>         "total": 55
>     }
> }
> ```

and this is the output i got from python console to print the "id" value

> ```
> import requests 
> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/people') 
> for i in r.json()["_items"]: print(i["id"])
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
> ```

i also tried to display the ID number outside the verticalHeader but to no avail

any insight would be very helpfull, thanks in advance

Comment: Change to `self.tview.setVerticalHeaderItem(row, QTableWidgetItem(str(item["id"])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @eyllanesc said.. change it to

```
self.tview.setVerticalHeaderItem(row, QTableWidgetItem(str(item["id"])))
```

does the trick. thanks